# Linking All Nodes of two types by ids

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

With the following code I create 2 types of nodes. In Neo4J

```
  public async Task CreateData()
  {
     AddNodesAsync<Companies>(myCompanies);
     AddNodesAsync<Employess>(myEmployes);
  }

  public Task AddNodesAsync<T>(List<T> nodes)
    {
        return client
            .Cypher
            .Create("(n:" + typeof(T).Name + " {nodes})")
            .WithParams(new {nodes})
            .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
    }
```

Each Employe has a company id.
Now I want to relate all of them when the id of the company of the employee matches the one on the company.

With the following code I can link **one** employe to **one** company

```
await client.Cypher
            .Match("(company:Company)", "(employee:Employee)")
            .Where((employee: company) => employee.ComanyId == company.Id)                       
            .Create("employee-[:BELONGS_TO]->company")
            .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
```

but how can I tell that it should link all employed by this id ref to their correspondand company?

Comment: I have this coded up and it works as expected - can you please copy your actual code you are executing, as the `Where` clause you have written wouldn't compile - it should look like: `.Where((Company company, Employee employee) => employee.CompanyId == company.Id)`

Comment: What do you mean by expected? In my case it seems like nothing happend. i don't see relations in neo4j. The type in where was because i was little simplifying the code.

Comment: I get all the relations created as expected, so if I have a company with Id 1, and 5 employees all with Company Id = 1, then I get 5 relations created.

Comment: hmm then i should have a typo somewhere. cam I right that in the match the first name (inmycaselowercase is the name of the variable, and after the : it is the name used in the database?) And is the order in the match or where important / related to the order in Create?

Comment: You are right, the `lowercase` is the identifier of the item in your query. The bit after the `:` is the Label, which in your case might be wrong, depending on the name of your class, so if you're class name is `Company`, then it would be `Company`, but if it's `Companies` it would be `Companies` - there is no ordering to worry about with the `Where` and the `Create` is all good

Comment: thx that was the solution ! I recommend you post it as reply and ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is a typo somewhere, this is the code I use which generates the links as you say it should.

Using these as the POCOs:

```
public class Company {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Employee {
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int CompanyId { get; set;}
}
```

Adding them:

```
var companies = new List<Company> { new Company { Id = 1 }, new Company {  Id = 2 } };
var employees = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee{ Id=1, CompanyId =1 },
    new Employee{ Id=2, CompanyId =1 },
    new Employee{ Id=3, CompanyId =1 },
    new Employee{ Id=4, CompanyId =2 },
    new Employee{ Id=5, CompanyId =2 },
};

await AddNodesAsync(companies);
await AddNodesAsync(employees);
```

This next bit generates the graph as you expect, with the relationships all created correctly.

```
await client.Cypher
    .Match("(company:Company)","(employee:Employee)")
    .Where((Company company, Employee employee) => employee.CompanyId == company.Id)
    .Create("(employee)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(company)")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```